# Buying tickets for travelling by train in Italy

Tags: trains, europe, italy

I am planning a trip to Italy this June and my itinerary is as follows.

1. 19 June Reaching Rome
2. 21 June Leaving for Florence.
3. 24 June Leaving for Venice.
4. 26 June Leaving for Milan.

I want recommendation for traveling by train between these places, ***cost is my priority over time taken to travel between the places***.

> I have found [Frecciarossa](http://www.italiarail.com/frecciarossa) and [Frecciabianca](http://www.italiarail.com/frecciabianca) trains running in Italy,
>   just wanted to know which one would be cheaper or is there any alternative beside these.

***I'll really appreciate if some one provides link to official website for above, as while searching on Google many options pop up, which one is good is hard to judge.***

From this [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/how-difficult-is-train-travel-in-italy) I found this link [Trenitalia](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=ad1ce14114bc9110VgnVCM10000080a3e90aRCRD), is this the right one to book tickets?

> Note: I am from India, can the tickets bought online or for foreigners
>   it is necessary to reach Italy and then only buy tickets, just
>   wondering if law of land prohibits?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://seat61.com/Italy.htm ? While unofficial, and oriented to British tourists, Seat61 is very reliable for train advice, especially in Europe, and include links to official sources and recommended guides.

Comment: It's an option.  There is no such thing right or wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How difficult is train travel in Italy?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/how-difficult-is-train-travel-in-italy)

Comment: @Karlson since new to this part of the world, having some doubts :)

Comment: @Karlson yup seen that also mentioned in my post link above, I am confused over type of trains in Italy, though google is there, needed some advice from people who know them fairly inside out

Comment: @gbagga That's not what you're asking in your question.

Comment: ALL YES I Have read "How difficult is train travel in Italy" but I am not satisfied with the answer.

Comment: i live in italy,
i agree : the right site is trenitalia.com

Comment: @user4550 welcome to the site. Your 'answer' was really a comment (see [faq]) so I moved it to the comment section.

Comment: @gbagga the answer on "How difficult is train travel in Italy"(http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/how-difficult-is-train-travel-in-italy) is almost identical to the one you accepted.  What was unacceptable about the other one? (you said you were not satisfied with it)

Comment: @MarkMayo I had many questions in mind like cost and what each name 'Frecciarossa' is all about, what so special about one than other, which website to use, I am foreigner can I buy from outside Italy or are there some restrictions etc..... but most of the questions I had in my mind are answered on seat61 Italy page. Thanks to Macrcel and choster. All I needed was right and reliable information to start research :), random googling was not giving well directed information on trains.

Comment: @gbagga The point that Mark and I were trying to make is: the question you asked is too similar to the ones already asked on this site.  You could have used this site to search for *train travel* multiple questions and answers have mentioned [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com).  If you have additional questions that haven't been answered and you wanted to ask then you should ask them instead.

Comment: @Karlson how many results this query gives http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=train+travel+italy+seat61

Comment: @gbagga Why do you want to narrow it to Italy specifically up front.  [Start broad](http://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=train+travel+europe).  Then narrow it down

Comment: OK unfortunately this question has become too much of a mess.  It's asking for recommendations (against the [faq]) although semi-specific.  It's only very tenuously different to another question, as commented. The question in the question differs from the title question, and then is different again in the comments.  I'm sorry, but I've got to close it.  Please do hop into the [chat] if you have any concerns, or feel free to rephrase in a new question which is consistent and matches the [faq]. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Trenitalia.com](http://www.trenitalia.com/) is indeed the right site to book the tickets for your trip. If you book online, you receive an electronic ticket. All you need is an e-mail address and a printer to print out your tickets.

The system will usually show you several prices: 1st class, 2nd class, flexible, restrictive, special deals, ... Note that all else being equal, the cheaper tickets tend to be more restrictive. Check the conditions before booking.

[The Italy page at seat61.com](http://seat61.com/Italy.htm) is highly recommended.

Comment: Once again thanks Marcel for the answer, seat61 page is really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. My personal favorite among these cities is Florence ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are usually trains leaving every couple of hours for your train service.

While booking in advance is nice, this is one of the few times I usually just pick up my ticket when I'm at the station. Trenitalia is the national rail service, and runs an express and a local. It sucks if you buy your ticket and miss your train, as it's a pain to change tickets, but if you buy when you're there, you can always just get on the one that's leaving next.

Enjoy Italy!